# Excel Conditional Formatting Loop

Tags: loops, excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I have this code:

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=IF($B5=""ARC"",1,0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = ColorSheet.Range("ARC_Color").Interior.Color
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False


Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=IF($B5=""ALL"",1,0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = ColorSheet.Range("ALL_Color").Interior.Color
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

There are more blocks than this and basically all that changes are the named ranges referenced inside the Conditional Formatting conditions.

```
=IF($B5=""ALL"",1,0)
ColorSheet.Range("ALL_Color").Interior.Color
```

what is the best way to loop this?
So that I don't have ten blocks of the code that is just exactly the same?

Can I alter it to read the named ranges off of a list on a separate sheet?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a procedure like this, that loops through a range on a separate worksheet, called "Variables" in this example. The range just contains your 10 changing values:

EDIT: modfified per @KillerSnail's fix in comments, and added a parameter to pass ColorSheet.

```
Sub LoopCF()
Dim wsVariables As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ColorSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim cell As Excel.Range

Set wsVariables = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Variables")
Set ColorSheet = ActiveSheet ' Change to suit your needs
'this range contains "All", "ARC", etc.
For Each cell In wsVariables.Range("A2:A11")
    ApplyCF cell.Value2
Next cell
End Sub
```

Then you basically call your existing code from the loop, passing "ARC", "ALL" and the other variables.

```
Sub ApplyCF(wsColorSheet As Excel.Worksheet, ConditionToCheck As String)

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=IF($B5=" & Chr(34) & ConditionToCheck & Chr(34) & ",1,0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = wsColorSheet.Range(ConditionToCheck & "_Color").Interior.Color
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Comment: If I use: .Color = ColorSheet.Range(ConditionToCheck & "_Color").Interior.Color I get "Error 424 Object required" If I use .Color = ColorSheet.Range(ConditionToCheck & "_Color").Interior.Color I get "Error 13 Type mismatch". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok in order for "=IF($B5=" & ConditionToCheck & ",1,0)" to work in the sub routine, I need to use "=IF($B5=" & Chr(34) & ConditionToCheck & Chr(34) & ",1,0)" otherwise the formula doesn't appear correctly.

Comment: Is there a way I can pass the definition of "ColorSheet" into the subroutine?

Comment: Sorry about gettting the quotes wrong - I knew I should have tested that better! See my edit for how to pass ColorSheet.

Comment: thank you @DougGlancy, i don't want to lock to the cell B5 - i want to check a condition according to the current cell i am iterating through - any idea how one can do that?